python to read a Bazel file and form unified string in loop
Team,
I have this Bazel file that I want to read in python and form a string
output should be string like this arm_base: artifactory.build.team.com/docker/ast/arm  should be combination of $registry and $repository
Command> cat ners.bzl 
"""
This module enumerates all base container images
"""

CONTAINERS = {
    "arm_base": {
        "registry": "artifactory.build.team.com",
        "repository": "docker/ast/arm",
    },
    "ast_base": {
        "registry": "artifactory.build.team.com",
        "repository": "docker/ast/tree",
    },

